# Can water in conduit cause an increase in voltage?

Tags: voltage

I'm a electrical & solar contractor. We installed a 38 kW system consisting of 3 inverters and (120) 320 watt panels, 40 per inverter. When we energize each inverter the voltage increases all along the system. I've got all the voltages if you need them. The inverter company had us bypass all breakers, fuses and bussing to confirm no unacceptable resisatance when systems are rpoducing power. And the utility came out and reworked all connections from transformer to meter. Inverter company suggested all this and we complied. Voltage increase still exists. When 1st system turned on voltage goes from 244 to 251. When 2nd system turned on voltage goes from 251 to 259.5. When 3rd comes on it goes from 259.5 to 267.6. Any combination of inverters on and off produce like results. Now the inverter tech support people say water in the conduit can cause this.  The wire is 4/0 AL XHHW. The most amperage recorded is 111 but mostly it runs at about 80 amps. All new wire and equipment. I'm not an engineer. Do you have any suggestions as to the cause of this? I've googled this question and also looked in advance search in this forum.

Comment: Water in a conduit isn't going to magically increase voltage flowing through an insulated cable.

Comment: Where are you measuring the voltage?  If it were me, I'd probably follow the path all the way from the inverter to the utility tie-in.  If the voltage is high right where the system connects to the utility, I'd be handing the problem off to the utility company.

Comment: We've measured all along the way at every measuring point. When the systems are off we have utility voltage 122/244. Turn on any one inverter and voltage at all points goes up to 251 v. Turn on a second inverter V goes up to 260. Turn on a 3rd inverter and it goes to 268v.  The water in the conduit theory is hard to imagine. Thousands of conduits from utilities have water in them.

Comment: You're basically saying that the voltage rises by about 8V for every 26.7A you add to the system, which implies that there's a *net effective impedance* of about 0.300 ohms between your connection and the utility's nearest distribution transformer. This would include wiring resistance, the winding resistance of the transformer and the transformed impedance of the rest of the grid connected to the primary. 4/0 aluminum is about 0.080 ohms/kfeet, so if you're 2000 feet from the transformer, that would account for it all by itself.

Comment: Distance from inverters to meter on property is about 225 feet with 4/0. I've since learned that the utility wire is 1/0 AL. Estimated distance meter to transformer is 400'.

Comment: OK, so 450' of 4/0 Al is about 0.036 ohms, and 800' of 1/0 AL is about 0.128 ohms, adding up to 0.164 ohms, so there's half your problem right there. The impedance of the transformer itself, the connections in the circuit, and the grid beyond probably account for the rest.

Comment: The utility, PG&E, requires us to install 3" conduit for 200 amp services. THis 30 year plus installation is fed by 1/0. Seems to me if PG&E upgraded their service entrance that this issue would go away. I'm not sure what their current minimum size conductors are but would think with underground involved it has to be at least 3/0 AL. Does this sound right? I'm a 37 year electrical contractor with little formal theory education. In this instance it really shows. I'm very appreciative of your participation and willingness to share your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage at the inverter's output needs to be greater than grid voltage if the current has to flow into the grid. It depends on grid impedance how much this voltage will rise for the same current. Simple ohms law : U=R*I can be writen as (Uinverter-U_grid)=I_inverter * R_grid, then Uinverter = I_inverter * R_grid + U_grid. It is prety trivial that voltage rise will be greater if grid impedance is larger (long distance to the transformer or small wires cross section).
As long the voltage rise is in the tolerance (approx +10%) the inverter will not limit the output voltage. If the voltage is limited, then the system cannot deliver the full available power from PV array.

Comment: The inverter was factory set at IEEE upper limit of 267 v I believe. One of the 3 would drop out once all 3 were active and the voltage passed the limit. Inverter tech raised upper limit to 273 as an experiment. Inverters passed it and still dropped out. Utility cleaned up all their connections. we are using 4/0 AL XHHW. Maximum amp reading so far is 111 amps. Mostly the amps are down around 80 to 85.